# How to refresh/reload a Fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I load a fragment twice, it just gets loaded above the contents of the same fragment that was loaded earlier.

I have this code to load it -

```
Fragment newFragment = new GridFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.gridFrame, newFragment).commit();

// gridFrame is the FrameLayout over which I replace it with the fragment
```

How do I just refresh the fragment and not load again above the prior contents ?

Comment: give your fragment a tag while adding and then refer that fragment using the same tag for e.g - > `(GridFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YOUR_TAG")`

Comment: If you set the Background color to white for all the Layouts of the Fragment, your content might not be conflict or gets loaded above the contents of the same fragment that was loaded earlier.

Comment: As per Muhammad Umer's answer, I used .replace() instead of .add()  .. It now reloads/refreshes the Fragment .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.replace()` instead of `.add()`.